# How can I distribute an amount of ether between a number of addresses based on percentages?

Tags: contract-development, ether, gambling

[full contract code](http://pastebin.com/raw/0AfNaV7u)

I have a contract (code above) where ether is bet on either side 0 or side 1. A winning side is determined (payout function), and the amount of ether that a winner will receive is determined by this formula:

`(amount wei winner bet/amount of wei in winning pool)*(amt. of wei in winning pool + amt. of wei in losing pool)`

The problem is that sometimes the formula will give a value of 0 when run on the contract when it doesn't in real life causing nobody to be paid. What's the best way to distribute the amount of ether that a winner deserves?

Comment: Help me please and tell me where you found it?

Answer (score 2):

found it out myself, i multiplied all percentages by 10000 so they wouldnt be rounded down to 0.